# UICollectionView vs. iCarousel (continuous loop, snapping, etc.)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, icarousel

I need to make a collection view with a continuous loop of the contents.  So, for instance, if the cell items have the integers 1 through 10, then when you hit 10, the next item in the list is 1, so that there is no stopping point.

I do not see an easy way to do that without subclassing and doing some custom offset manipulation.  This is making me think iCarousel may be a better solution.

I also need to snap the cell to the center, making a sort of selection, and manipulate the appearance of that cell, which iCarousel seems to handle nicely.

My only problem is that is seems that using UICollectionView is a better approach, and I have read some (seemingly off-hand) comments about iCarousel being a poor approach.

Is there a way to do these things with a UICollectionView, or is iCarousel a good component/approach for solving these issues?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can do this the same way you can with a table view. You return a very large number for numberOfItemsInSection, and then in cellForItemAtIndexPath: you use the modulus operator to convert that number to a number between 0 and 9:

```
cell.label.text = [self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row % 10];
```

I'm not really sure how to do the "snap the cell to the center" thing, but there's an example of that in the WWDC 2012 session 219 - Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts.

Comment: rdelmar, I am accepting your answer, which looks like it will work after investigating; however, I ended up using iCarousel as it was a much more expedient solution for me.

Comment: To everyone, make sure your "numberOfItemsInSection" is very large.